# Serilog Filters - Configured in C#

Tags: serilog, serilog-filter

I am attempting to support multiple sinks from a single logger. Sometimes we need to write to a database, other times to file. From what I've read it seems that 'Filters' are the way to go...

I can successfully configure serilog to write logs to my database with custom formatting etc.
(I have this working without issue)
`logConfig.WriteTo.ApplicationDatabase(connectionString).`

My challenge is now to write logs to one sink(ApplicationDatabase) or the other(file) depending upon whether the **enriched** log contains a particular property ['SpecialEvent' (string)] that is not null.

So far I have the following. I get the file created on disk, but it seems that the logs are being written to both the database and the file.  Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

```
                    .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
                    .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(le => isSpecialEventPresent(le)));

                    serilogConfig.WriteTo.File(@".\logs\LocalFile.log")
                    .Filter.ByExcluding(le => isSpecialEventPresent(le));
```

The predicate defined for the filter...

```
                        LogEventPropertyValue eventVal;
                        if (le.Properties.TryGetValue("SpecialEvent", out eventVal) &&
                                eventVal is ScalarValue &&
                                ((ScalarValue)eventVal).Value != null)
                        {
                            return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(eventVal.ToString());
                        }

                        return false;
                    };
```